# Error de compilacion PDF Rstudio Latex

Tags: r, rstudio, latex, r-markdown

Al querer compilar este codigo de Latex en la plataforma Rstudio

```
\documentclass{article} %Tipo de Documento
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Paquete de codificación
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\title{TSP Tunel Correa Salida}
\author{Miguel Eduardo Mogollon Olivares}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

El principal grupo en ese momento correspondía al que lo año setenta fue ``bautizado'' como grupo sudamericano, que algunos lo llamaban el Sindicato Antioqueño y otros el grupo Emopresarial Antioqueño, con unos axtivos equivalentes al 15.7\% del PBI, unos \$ 15 millones de dólares estadounidenses, cuando en los años setenta ocupaba el cuarto puesto , con activos equivalentes a 7.3\% del PBI; es decir, mas que duplicó su peso realtivo.

\end{document}
```

Me aparece este error:

```
You can now run (pdf)latex on 'latex.tex'
Running pdflatex.exe on latex.tex...failed
Error running C:/Users/MIGUEL~1/AppData/Local/Programs/MIKTEX~1.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe (exit code 1)
```

Quiero saber como solucionarlo o que tengo que hacer para que me compile en PDF.

Comment: El comando `\SweaveOpts` no es parte del LaTeX estándar, y tampoco veo que uses ningún paquete en donde pudiera estar definido ese comando. Parece que tu texto no usa ninguna característica de knitr o sweave por lo que yo simplemente quitaría esa línea y probaría a compilar de nuevo.

Comment: Muy bueno... resultó... gracias...@abulafia